# Using "CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP" probes on Cisco ASR router

Tags: ping, cisco-nexus, smokeping

I hope to calculate latency between 2 ASR router on specific VRF.
`Smokeping` configuration looks like this:

```
!
*** Probes ***
+ FPing
binary = /usr/sbin/fping

+ CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP
forks = 5
offset = 50%
step = 300
timeout = 15

*** Targets ***
+ CISCO

probe = CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP
menu = Cisco router
host = Target_IP_router
ioshost = Source_IP_router
packetsize = 56
pings = 5
timeout = 15
tos = 160
vrf = VRF_test
!
```

Both files `CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP.pm` and `ciscoRttMonMIB.pm` are copied to `/etc/smokeping/lib/Smokeping/` and
`snmp-server community RTTCommunity RW` is implemented on the source router.

When I try to run `smokeping --debug`, I get the error message below :
"

```
CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP: probing 1 targets with step 300 s and offset 45 s.
FPing: probing 51 targets with step 300 s and offset 45 s.
CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP: forks 5, timeout for each target 76
172.24.32.67:::::2 doesn't support or allow RTTMon !
CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP: 10.248.17.202: got
```

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `ioshost` must include the SNMP community in the form of `RTTCommunity@185.233.143.1`.

Please note that if you've tried to copy the sample config from https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP.en.html then you probably have

```
 ioshost = RTTcommunity@Myrouter.foobar.com.au # mandatory
```

But on the same page in the IOS config examples the community string is `RTTCommunity`. (Mind the capital "C".)

Smokeping can't connect to the Cisco device with wrong or missing SNMP community and can't query the version of the RTTMON MIB and shows the error in your example. (Please see the [source code](https://github.com/oetiker/SmokePing/blob/b79da17d63103bb3844990f38bba1514a5136918/lib/Smokeping/probes/CiscoRTTMonEchoICMP.pm#L163).)

So in this case the correct config would be:

```
 ioshost = RTTCommunity@Myrouter.foobar.com.au # mandatory
```